# AFrame: how to programmatically create a grid of canvas textured planes

Tags: aframe

I'm not quite understanding how aframe want things done at init time from JavaScript. I created a grid component that creates NxM planes, each with it's own canvas for a texture. But for some reason the even though the canvases are unique, 1 per plane, they are randomly re-used per plane

What I should see is a grid that's like

```
+---+ +---+ +---+
| 6 | | 7 | | 8 |
+---+ +---+ +---+
+---+ +---+ +---+
| 3 | | 4 | | 5 |
+---+ +---+ +---+
+---+ +---+ +---+
| 0 | | 1 | | 2 |
+---+ +---+ +---+
```

What I see instead is something like

[image]

I could be doing something stupid. Here's the code. Note: it's all stuck in the HTML section because of the way aframe works.

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
AFRAME.registerComponent('grid', {
  schema: {
    across: {type: 'int', default: 3},
    down: {type: 'int', default: 3},
  },
  init() {
    const data = this.data;
    const across = data.across;
    const down = data.down;
    const needed = across * down;
    for (let i = 0; i < needed; ++i) {
      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = 256;
      canvas.height = 256;
      canvas.id = `c${Date.now()}`;
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.fillStyle = `hsl(${i / needed * 360 | 0}deg,100%,50%)`;
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 256, 256);
      ctx.fillStyle = `hsl(${Math.random() * 360 | 0}deg,100%,80%)`;
      ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
      ctx.font = '200px sans-serif';
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
      ctx.fillText(i, 128, 128);
      const elem = document.createElement('a-entity');
      elem.setAttribute('geometry', {
        primitive: 'plane',
        height: 1,
        width: 1,
      });
      elem.setAttribute('material', {
        shader: 'flat',
        src: canvas,
      });
      this.el.appendChild(elem);
      const x = i % across;
      const y = i / across | 0;
      const u = x / (across - 1);
      const v = y / (down - 1);
      const px = across * (u - .5);
      const py = down * (v - .5);
      const pz = 0;
      elem.setAttribute('position', {x: px, y: py, z: pz});
    }
  },
});
</script>
<a-scene>
  <a-entity grid position="0 1.5 -4"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

I also tried adding the canvases to the DOM and referencing by assigning ids. The relevant lines are

```
  // make up an ID
  canvas.id = `c${Date.now()}`;

  // add to document
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);

  // make the src the id of the canvas
  elem.setAttribute('material', {
    shader: 'flat',
    src: `#${canvas.id}`,
  });
```

But it has the same problem

[image]

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
AFRAME.registerComponent('grid', {
  schema: {
    across: {type: 'int', default: 3},
    down: {type: 'int', default: 3},
  },
  init() {
    const data = this.data;
    const across = data.across;
    const down = data.down;
    const needed = across * down;
    for (let i = 0; i < needed; ++i) {
      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = 256;
      canvas.height = 256;
      canvas.id = `c${Date.now()}`;
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.fillStyle = `hsl(${i / needed * 360 | 0}deg,100%,50%)`;
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 256, 256);
      ctx.fillStyle = `hsl(${Math.random() * 360 | 0}deg,100%,80%)`;
      ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
      ctx.font = '200px sans-serif';
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
      ctx.fillText(i, 128, 128);
      const elem = document.createElement('a-entity');
      elem.setAttribute('geometry', {
        primitive: 'plane',
        height: 1,
        width: 1,
      });
      elem.setAttribute('material', {
        shader: 'flat',
        src: `#${canvas.id}`,
      });
      this.el.appendChild(elem);
      const x = i % across;
      const y = i / across | 0;
      const u = x / (across - 1);
      const v = y / (down - 1);
      const px = across * (u - .5);
      const py = down * (v - .5);
      const pz = 0;
      elem.setAttribute('position', {x: px, y: py, z: pz});
    }
  },
});
</script>
<a-scene>
  <a-entity grid position="0 1.5 -4"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because a-frame is creating the entities so fast that it makes Date.now not unique.

Outside the loop, try:

```
let id = 0;
```

then for the id:

```
canvas.id = `c${id++}`;
```

And it seems to work as expected.

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
AFRAME.registerComponent('grid', {
  schema: {
    across: {type: 'int', default: 3},
    down: {type: 'int', default: 3},
  },
  init() {
    const data = this.data;
    const across = data.across;
    const down = data.down;
    const needed = across * down;
    let id = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < needed; ++i) {
      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = 256;
      canvas.height = 256;
      canvas.id = `c${id++}`;
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.fillStyle = `hsl(${i / needed * 360 | 0}deg,100%,50%)`;
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 256, 256);
      ctx.fillStyle = `hsl(${Math.random() * 360 | 0}deg,100%,80%)`;
      ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
      ctx.font = '200px sans-serif';
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
      ctx.fillText(i, 128, 128);
      const elem = document.createElement('a-entity');
      elem.setAttribute('geometry', {
        primitive: 'plane',
        height: 1,
        width: 1,
      });
      elem.setAttribute('material', {
        shader: 'flat',
        src: `#${canvas.id}`,
      });
      this.el.appendChild(elem);
      const x = i % across;
      const y = i / across | 0;
      const u = x / (across - 1);
      const v = y / (down - 1);
      const px = across * (u - .5);
      const py = down * (v - .5);
      const pz = 0;
      elem.setAttribute('position', {x: px, y: py, z: pz});
    }
  },
});
</script>
<a-scene>
  <a-entity grid position="0 1.5 -4"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: DOH! Like I said I was doing something stupid, although the fact that aframe needs IDs at all seems kind of wonky :(